# Room compile problem - column references a foreign key but it is not part of an index

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm new to android app development and am creating an app that has Trips which stores Locations.

I'm getting a compile error :"trip_Id column references a foreign key but it is not part of an index. This may trigger full table scans whenever parent table is modified so you are highly advised to create an index that covers this column."

I have 2 tables: Trip & Location.

I've tried indexing the tripId and the locationId in their respective classes but it doesn't solve the issue.

A Trip has its id (PK), title, description and priority.

A Location has its locationId (PK), tripId(FK), locationName and LatLng of the place.

```
@Entity(tableName = "location_table",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Trip.class, parentColumns = "location_Id", childColumns = "trip_Id"),
        indices = {@Index(value = {"locationId"}, unique = true)})
public class Location {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int locationId;

    @ColumnInfo (name = "trip_Id")
    private int tripId;

    private String locationName;

    @TypeConverters(LatLngConverter.class)
    private LatLng latLng;


@Entity(tableName = "trip_table", indices = {@Index(value = {"id"}, unique = true)})

public class Trip {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) // with each new row SQLite will automatically increment this ID so it will be unique
    @ColumnInfo (name = "location_Id")
    private int id;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private int priority;
```

I can't seem to find out what's wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That message is a warning, there would be other errors (see 2nd suggested line). e.g.

[image]

Using `indices = {@Index(value = {"locationId"}, unique = true),@Index(value = {"trip_Id"})})` should overcome that warning.

**HOWEVER**, there is no need to have an (additional) index on **locationId** as it is already indexed being the primary key (this would be a waste and also inefficient). So it is suggested that you use :-

```
indices = {@Index(value = {"trip_Id"})})
```

I believe that your overall issue is that you are referring to the object's variable name for the column, when if you have `@ColumnInfo(name ="????")` then you should be referring to the given name

- i.e. ???? is the column name in the underlying table.

You should also be using **location_Id** instead of **id** in the Trip:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "trip_table", indices = {@Index(value = {"location_Id"}, unique = true)})
```

Comment: This solved the problem, however, I''m getting another error now.


"error: trip_table table referenced in the foreign keys of com.example.travelplanner.Location does not exist in the database. Maybe you forgot to add the referenced entity in the entities list of the @Database annotation?"


I do not understand what this means. I have created the Trip database before adding the Location database in and it had worked fine, being able to place the data and display them on RecyclerView.

Comment: @Ferain In the `@Database` annotation you need to specify **`Trip.class`** in the list of Entities.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I had quite a few foreign keys. I found out (after a lot of trial and error) that I set up my indices wrong... whoops. :P

**Wrong:**

```
indices = [
    Index("active_color_style_id",
        "ambient_color_style_id",
        "hour_hand_dimensions_id",
        "minute_hand_dimensions_id",
        "second_hand_dimensions_id")
]
```

**Right:**

```
indices = [
    Index("active_color_style_id"),
    Index("ambient_color_style_id"),
    Index("hour_hand_dimensions_id"),
    Index("minute_hand_dimensions_id"),
    Index("second_hand_dimensions_id")
]
```

**Full example:**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "analog_watch_face_table",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = WatchFaceColorStyleEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["active_color_style_id"],
            onDelete = NO_ACTION
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = WatchFaceColorStyleEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["ambient_color_style_id"],
            onDelete = NO_ACTION
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = WatchFaceArmDimensionsEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["hour_hand_dimensions_id"],
            onDelete = NO_ACTION
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = WatchFaceArmDimensionsEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["minute_hand_dimensions_id"],
            onDelete = NO_ACTION
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = WatchFaceArmDimensionsEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["second_hand_dimensions_id"],
            onDelete = NO_ACTION
        )
    ],
    indices = [
        Index("active_color_style_id"),
        Index("ambient_color_style_id"),
        Index("hour_hand_dimensions_id"),
        Index("minute_hand_dimensions_id"),
        Index("second_hand_dimensions_id")
    ]
)
```

Comment: How can I migrate to this though? I mean, I have Room already set without indices (users have it being set as such), so how can I let them migrate to the new change?

Comment: You can bump the version and migrate them from the old one to the new one. [Here's the guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions).

Comment: I know how migrations work. I just ask in this case, of creating the index. Is it possible to modify a table to have an index? Or do I have to create an entirely new table for each table that has no index, fill it, and remove the previous one?

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry, Hmm... that's a good question. I didn't have indexes on by tables when I started with the first versions, so I would assume it's ok to add them, but  I was prototyping through it pretty fast for this simplified sample (not production app). You probably need to test it. Sorry I don't have a better answer. :-/

Comment: I mean: How do you add indices to a table that didn't have it before (in the migration) ?